# problem with special characters on Dialogflow-skype messages

Tags: skype, dialogflow-es

Right now i am developing a chat bot using Dialogflow(API.AI) and the problem is when i send a message that contains a apostrophe(') the bot shows it as **&apos** , is there any way to show it as the original character?

for example look the image:
[image]
The message name is "Ricardo's Party" but when dialogflow returns the message it says "Ricardo&apost;s Party" there is any way to change that response message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the end, the problem was with the characters ' and " i solved the problem sending the message to the webhook(javascript backend) replacing all &apost; and " with "\'" and "\"" and then returning the new message to skype.